# How do I implement Tab navigation in React Native + Expo without making everything look janky?

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile, expo, react-navigation

For my app, I'm currently using Expo routers built in tab navigation, however I am running into some issues making the tab bar disappear with an animation (reanimated). Right now I make my tabs disappear using the display styling. I set it to 'flex' when I need it to show and 'none' when I need it to disappear.

How would I be able to implement some sort of animation whenever it does go away? Can I still use expo tab navigation or would I have to build my own tab bar to have that functionality?

I really want to implement a sort of swipe down to make tab disappear and swipe up to make it appear feature!